# How to create normal users and access Realtime database under admin user in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I had completed `Firebase` phone authentication for admin user. Admin needs to register phone numbers of normal users under his account. With only that registered phone number normal users can signup and access database of that admin.
Normal users need to read/write data as same as the parent of admin.What to do? Any Android `Firebase` Developers,please help!

Comment: so you want to check if a user who is signing up with phone has his phone number present under user node ?

Comment: yes it is what i want.

Comment: Please see this post you need a multi step signup : See this post and then try to build your own setup
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/multi-step-signup-firebase-email-password-auth-angular-reactive-forms/

Comment: i am a noob in angularFirebase , And i don't have enough time to learn that..Will you please share an another solution...?

Comment: There is no such thing as an *admin* user in Firebase; all users are just users. The solution will depend on how an admin user is defined and how it's stored in Firebase. Also, this is leaning toward a multi-tenant structure which Firebase is not the best at. Finally, having one user 'register' or 'create' other users instead of them registering themselves has some additional challenges with authentication so it's probably not a good idea. You may want to re-think the approach in general; have users sign themselves up for your app is a good starting point.